# Sum sales by day and time period

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to add sales that happened daily by time period.
I used sumifs to get sales by date, but I can’t figure it out by day and time period.

For example:
Sales from 8am -12:00 pm, 12-5 pm on 11/20/21

Comment: Why not just use the date but include time.  A date without time is simply a date at 12AM date + 1 hour = date + (1/24) so you would still look between 2 dates but the dates would include hours.

Answer (score 0):

**QUERY**

**Sales from 8am -11:59 am on 11/20/21**

- `=query({A2:C8},"select sum(Col3) where  Col1 >= datetime '2021-11-20 08:00:00' and Col1 <= datetime '2021-11-20 11:59:59' label sum(Col3) '' ",0)`

**Sales from 12:00pm - 04:59 pm on 11/20/21**

- `=query({A2:C8},"select sum(Col3) where  Col1 >= datetime '2021-11-20 12:00:00' and Col1 <= datetime '2021-11-20 16:59:59' label sum(Col3) '' ",0)`

---

**SUMIFS**

**Sales from 8am -11:59 am on 11/20/21**

- `=sumifs(C2:C,A2:A,">=20/11/2021 08:00:00", A2:A,"<=20/11/2021 11:59:00")`

**Sales from 12:00pm - 04:59 pm on 11/20/21**

- `=sumifs(C2:C,A2:A,">=20/11/2021 12:00:00", A2:A,"<=20/11/2021 16:59:00")`

**Note:**
You asked for "Sales from 8am -12:00 pm, 12-5 pm on 11/20/21".
If there was a sale at 12:00pm, then it would be included in both calculations. So, you need to define the start or end time so that it is not duplicated in each formula.

---

**Sample**

[image: snapshot]